# Manifest merger failed error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest

I am in the process of moving my current projects huge application into Android Studio and Gradle. I am currently stuck on the following issue:

```
Error:(87, 9) Execution failed for task ':App:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(@string/app_label) from AndroidManifest.xml:87:9
    is also present at ANDROID_APPLICATION:Library:unspecified:9:18 value=(@string/app_name)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:82:5 to override
```

I have tried adding the following attributes to the main `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
tools:replace="android:label, *App Name*"
tools:replace="android:label, @string/app_label"
tools:replace="android:label"
```

None of these attribute definitions works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Give this a try:

Add this to `<manifest/>`

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Add this to `<application/>`

```
tools:node="replace"
```

Based on [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#merge_rule_markers), it should override all the elements. "Replace the lower priority declaration with the annotated one."

Comment: thanks a lot. for some reason `tools:replace` refuses to work, but this works (possibly a bit eagerly, though)

Comment: this is not working for me in AS 1.3.2 with gradle plugin 1.2.3 or 1.3.0

Comment: This issue is due to issue in Manifest file or build.gradle file. You can check my post 
https://wordpress.com/post/dhingrakimmi.wordpress.com/23

Comment: In my case string was missing

Comment: After app build successfully then immediately app crashed.

Comment: @kayvan after using(tools:node="replace") this i am getting crash in firebase setup

Comment: is there any way to add this xmlns to android manifest from config.xml for ionic ?

Comment: For the love of all that is holy DO NOT USE THIS IF YOU USE FIREBASE. I wasted 2 days trying to understand why my Firebase setup wasn't working, and finally traced it back to this.

Answer (score 41):

## Background

When the manifest files are being merged, there is a conflict with the `label` attribute.

In general, [there are three types](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) of manifest files that need to be merged into a single resulting app manifest, here in priority order :

1. Product flavors and build types specific manifest files.
2. Main manifest file for the application.
3. Library manifest files.

### Resolutions

The conflict can be resolved in one of two ways:-

#### Remove the conflicting label

Remove the conflicting attribute from the library (or lower-level) manifest file.

In this case, the `ANDROID_APPLICATION:Library:unspecified:9:18 value=(@string/app_name)` has a `@string/app_name` value defined that's different from that in the main application. So if it's not required, then remove it -- simply remove the `android:label="@string/app_name"` from the library file's `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

#### Add an attribute to allow an automatic resolution to the conflict

There are [several special attribute markers](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:node-markers) (in the tools namespace) that may be used to express a specific decision for how to resolve conflicts.

In this case, to explicitly cause the main app's `android:label` to override any other (e.g. library file) application labels, add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` definition to the `<manifest>` node, and `tools:replace="label"` to the `<application>` node.

Here is an example - use this in the main application's `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="label"/>
</manifest>
```

This approach would also work with any other conflicting attributes; for example if the `icon` attribute was also in conflict, it could be changed to `tools:replace="label, icon"`.

Comment: this is not working for me in AS 1.3.2 with gradle plugin 1.2.3 or 1.3.0

Comment: This worked for me in 1.4 (nice thorough description btw.)

Comment: Is there any specific reason why android:label would be required/wanted in library's app manifest?

Comment: @BlažŠnuderl I haven't tried without this, as it is the basis of labels used (and presented to users) in Activities within an application.  See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#label

Comment: why would manifest files even be merged?  i started getting this error after a normal build, I hadn't even done anything aside from edit java source files!

Comment: @Michael Did you inadvertently add a reference to another package/library that happened to have a definition of a label that's the same as an existing one?

Comment: I don't know... tracked it down and it turned out my manifest had the correct min version, but there was a gradle build file which did not (easy enough to fix) leading to the question of why the build ever worked at all.

Answer (score 6):

If you were fortunate, as I was, you can manually fix the problem with a hacky work-around.

AAR files are just .zip files with an .aar extension.  In my case, I unzipped the .aar, removed the offending `android:label` from the library's `AndroidManifest.xml`, and then rearchived the remaining files with a .aar extension and everything seems to work perfectly with the new .aar.

FYI, [this appears to be a known bug in the android gradle plugin](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72450).

Comment: this worked for me. all other solutions didnt worked

Answer (score 4):

I fixed same issue. Solution for me:

1. add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` line in the manifest tag
2. add `tools:replace=..` in the manifest tag
3. move `android:label=...` in the manifest tag

[Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40306041/5489153)

Answer (score 1):

I just removed

`android:label="@string/app_name`

from the `manifest file` and it worked!

Comment: this is working but it also change the app display name.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the manifest file from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:name=".SomeActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

To

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:label">
        <activity android:name=".SomeActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And now the `android:label` is replaced by the label from the parent application.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issues, and after lot of research found the soultion

> 1. your min sdk version should be same as of the modules you are using
>      eg: your module min sdk version is 14 and your app min sdk version is 9
>      It should be same.
> 2. If build version of your app and modules not same. Again it should same

**In short, your app build.gradle file and manifest should have same configurations**

> 3. There's no duplicacy like same permissions added in manifest file twice, same activity mention twice
> 4. If you have delete any activity from your project, delete it from your manifest file as well
> 5. Sometimes its becuase of label, icon etc tag of manifest file
>      a)  add the xmlns:tools line in the manifest tag
>      b) add tools:replace= or tools:ignore=in the application tag 
>      **Example**

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.slinfy.ikharelimiteduk"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<application
    tools:replace="icon, label"
    android:label="myApp"
    android:name="com.example.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
</application>
</manifest>
```

By considering these points in mind, you will get rid of this manifest merger failed issue
Check my post: This issue is due to issue in Manifest file or build.gradle file. You can check my post 
https://wordpress.com/post/dhingrakimmi.wordpress.com/23

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true`
in `gradle.properties` file.
It helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. In my case `android:label` was empty in AndroidManifest.xml file. Then I changed it as below

`android:label="@string/app_name`

Maybe this simple solution will help someone. Thank you.