# Manifest Merger failed - InstrumentationTestRunner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have just recently migrated my library project from Eclipse to Android Studio 1.1.0. Every time i try to run test or clean the project, i get following error:

```
Error:(15, 22) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
    > java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : Attribute instrumentation#android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner@label value=(Tests for com.dummyname.lib) from manifestMerger3662930390325374798.xml:15:22
        is also present at debug:16:9 value=(Dummyname Tests)
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <instrumentation> element at manifestMerger3662930390325374798.xml:11:5 to override
```

I've put 'tools:replace="android:label"' into my AndroidManifest.xml but nothing happened. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095703/manifest-merger-failed-error)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens. I think that you need to check that all the resources in the resource folder has been copied successfully to the android studio from the eclipse. As far as I think you have missed the class/activity . you should check the following also.
1. no missing attribute
2. Dependency (Some times you declared the minimum sdk, and your app depends on something which is higher then the mentioned minimum sdk)
3. check if you are using external library in eclipse 
4. mismatch of minimum sdk in Manifest file and gradle file