# Manifest Merger Error when using Dynamic Features and Build Flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, android-build-flavors, dynamic-feature-module

With dynamic-feature-modules it is possible to define in the `AndroidManifest.xml` wheter a module should come preinstalled:

```
<dist:module
    ...
    dist:onDemand="false"
    dist:title="@string/title_shop">
    ....
</dist:module>
```

or not:

```
<dist:module
    ...
    dist:onDemand="true"
    dist:title="@string/title_shop">
    ....
</dist:module>
```

I have two build flavors in my project. The module should be preinstalled in one flavor but not in the other.

The idea is to have this default `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `main` source set:

```
<dist:module
    ...
    dist:onDemand="true"
    dist:title="@string/title_shop">
    ....
</dist:module>
```

For build flavors that should have the module preinstalled - I create a `AndroidManifest.xml` file that overrides that `dist:onDemand` property
to `false`:

```
<dist:module
    ...
    tools:replace="dist:onDemand"
    dist:onDemand="false"
    ...
</dist:module>
```

Unfortunately, this does *not* work. The Manifest Merger fails with the following errors:

> Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:11 for attribute dist:onDemand, but no new value specified shop manifest, line 10 Error: Validation failed, exiting shop manifest.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39957077/5197488) worked for me. The idea is to have two copies of the AndroidManifest.xml, which are identical except

```
<dist:module
    ...
    tools:node="replace"
    dist:onDemand="false">
    ...
</dist:module>
```

which [replaces the **whole element**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#node_markers).

Answer (score 0):

The manifest merger tool combines all XML elements from each file by following some merge heuristics. If the merger tool finds that both manifests contain the same attribute with different values, then a merge conflict occurs.

Docs:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [celaeno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57802101/1650674)

If I tried to have just `debug` and `release` (or whatever your two build types are) AndroidManifests that were full and exact copies except changes to  `dist:onDemand` line. This didnt' work. Gradle yelled at me about a missing `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. So I actually created three files:

1. main

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.example.somefeature">

    <application ...>
        <activity
            android:name=...
        </activity>
    </application>
 <!-- NO dist:module block -->
</manifest>
```

2. debug

   ```
   <dist:module
       dist:instant="false"
       dist:title="@string/somefeature">
       <dist:delivery>
           <dist:install-time />
       </dist:delivery>
       <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
   </dist:module>
   ```
3. release

   ```
   <dist:module
       dist:instant="false"
       dist:title="@string/somefeature">
       <dist:delivery>
           <dist:on-demand />
       </dist:delivery>
       <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
   </dist:module>
   ```