# How to exclude a dynamic feature from Android app flavor?

Tags: android, gradle, dynamic-feature-module

I have this project structure:

- app
- library1
- dynamicFeature1
- dynamicFeature2

Now, I want `dynamicFeature2` to only be included in my *development* builds, and never appear in anything that could be released.

I used *productFlavors* like this:

```
    productFlavors {
        public {
            dynamicFeatures = [':dynamicFeature1']
        }
        development {
            dynamicFeatures = [':dynamicFeature1', ':dynamicFeature2']
        }
    }
```

This way I have both features in *public** and *development** variants, however if I comment out the `dynamicFeatures` line for *development* flavor, I will only have `dynamicFeature1` in **both** flavors. So it kinda works, but not the way I want.

So, is there a way for app flavors to have different sets of dynamic features?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
And this solition help me

```
android{
...
    productFlavors {
        public {}
        development {}
    }

    def gradleStartTasks = gradle.getStartParameter().taskNames
    gradleStartTasks.forEach { taskName ->
    if (taskName.contains('Development')) {
        dynamicFeatures = [':dynamicFeature1', ':dynamicFeature2']
    } else if (taskName.contains('Public')) {
        dynamicFeatures = [':dynamicFeature1']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951262/manifest-merger-error-when-using-dynamic-features-and-build-flavors) question to solve it for now. I created a *development* source set for `dynamicFeature2`, where there is only a manifest file present. This manifest declares:

```xml
    <dist:module
        dist:instant="false"
        dist:title="@string/title_dynamic_feature_2"
        tools:node="replace">
        <dist:delivery>
            <dist:install-time />
        </dist:delivery>
        <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
    </dist:module>
```

The manifest in *main* source set uses `<dist:on-demand />`. This way I only have `dynamicFeature2` installed for *development** variants, and I don't make a *SplitInstallRequest* for this feature.

This is only a workaround, as the bundle still contains `dynamicFeature2` apk, which I hoped to not be built using gradle configuration.