# Manifest merger failed while running

Tags: android, android-manifest

**Android: Manifest merger failed com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0**

I seem to be getting the error of:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:percent:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

How can I solve this problem? This is my app's build.gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "tw.com.iac.sam_qw25"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    ...
}dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:16.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

And this is the project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: one of your dependencys have included support library as a dependency, so you need to make sure that the versionnumbers match. changing com.android.support:percent:26.0.2 to com.android.support:percent:26.1.0 should fix it

Comment: Thanks in advance for your opinion @JoachimHaglund but I got new error messages like:
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [com.android.support:percent:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
 is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.0.2).
Have any ideas about this error message?

Answer (score 1):

```
<application
    android:name=".app.MyApp"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:replace="android:value">
```

1. Go to your app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file
2. Inside the application tag, add the line

> tools:replace="android:value"

3. Clean/rebuild your project.

If such errors are occurring for more than one value, like icon, theme, use cleartext traffic, etc. are causing the same error, put them together in the tools: replace tag like this

```
 tools:replace="icon,theme,usesCleartextTraffic"
```