# Manifest Merger failed with error in Android Studio

Tags: android

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors. See logs:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

Comment: Post your complete error log

Comment: Did you declare android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion in manifest?

Comment: This link may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095703/manifest-merger-failed-error

Comment: yes i did declare android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion in manifest but getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Check out for Gradle Console for Errors like

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

These shouldn't be declared in Manifest files of libraries that you are using..etc

You can view these errors in Gradle console which you can find under

```
View -> Tools Window ->  Gradle Console
```