# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest

Tags: android

I am integrating payUMoney payment gateway with my android application but after integrating following error show in my Logcat

Logcat

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(Buy Wid US) from AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-35
    is also present at [PayBaniyyaIntegrate:payUMoneysdk:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:19:9-41 value=(@string/app_name)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-30:19 to override
```

after that I follow this link answer number 2
[Manifest merger failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095703/manifest-merger-failed-error?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
Error:(2) Resource entry activity_horizontal_margin is already defined.
```

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: i done it so many time