# Attribute permission#<YOUR PACKAGE>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE@name value=(.permission.C2D_MESSAGE)

Tags: android

**Manifest:**
[image: Error:Execution failed]

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed : Attribute permission#<YOUR PACKAGE>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE@name value=(.permission.C2D_MESSAGE) from AndroidManifest.xml
```

This error generate on Android Studio to build a project.
How to solve this error?

Comment: share your `AndroidManifest` as text not as image

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095703/manifest-merger-failed-error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (as the error message shows) the same permission is available in another manifest (firebase manifest). So you can remove it from your manifest to solve the problem (easy approach). You can also override it in your manifest like below:

```
<permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" 
        tools:replace="android:name"/>
```

For using tools you need to add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` line in the manifest tag as below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:allowBackup="false"
          android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write below code in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<manifest ...
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...>
```

And in the application tag ->

```
  <application
    ...
    tools:replace="android:name">
```