# How to update Firebase version in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase

Currently my gradle has this line:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'

I need to use version 19.1.0, but everytime I change it I get this error:

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-33:19 to override.

I've tried the solution of using tools:replace, but that just results in the whole thing breaking.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do it manually using the latest version from [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

Comment: Have a look to [Manifest merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28106780/7138532)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the latest Firebase versions. Your project must be migrated to AndroidX.