# Instabug error:- Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.instabug.library.InstabugFeedbackActivity@windowSoftInputMode

Tags: android, instabug

I am using Instabug with URBAN AIRSHIP getting the following error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.instabug.library.InstabugFeedbackActivity@windowSoftInputMode value=(adjustResize) from [com.instabug.library:instabug:2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:29:13-55
>       is also present at [com.instabug.library:instabugcore:1.7.4] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-52 value=(adjustPan).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:windowSoftInputMode"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:9-29:58 to override.

I go through 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger
and
[Tools: replace not replacing in Android manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/toolsreplace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest)

But didn't get any solution

//EDITED
already tried 
 tools:replace="android:windowSoftInputMode" 
No solution yet

Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:windowSoftInputMode"' to `<activity>` element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:9-29:58 to override.
HOW SHOULD I USE IT?

Answer (score 0):

Hello MobilityNewTech,

Seems like you have 2 different versions of Instabug imported (namely 1.7.4 & 2.0)

> from [com.instabug.library:instabug:**2.0**] AndroidManifest.xml:29:13-55 is also present at [com.instabug.library:instabugcore:**1.7.4**]

If you can post your `build.gradle` maybe I can help you fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started to use Instabug and a problem the same as yours occured when I used following dependency:

```
compile 'com.instabug.library:instabug:2+'
compile ("com.instabug.library:instabugsupport:+") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

`instabug` dependency was used because my app minSdk +14 and `instabugsupport` was used as a solution to following question:

> Is there a way to prevent Instabug from pulling the latest version of AppCompat?

from FAQ below configuration section.

Problem dissapeared when I changed it to it:

```
compile('com.instabug.library:instabugcompat:2.0.1')
```

I think Instabug should update whole configuration section - especially a part about using support libraries - e.g. when you're using Instabug 'developer console' to integrate your app with Instabug, it isn't clear, what dependency should I use when I'm using support libraries in app set for minSdk +14. Moreover, when you choose 'Support library', they prompt you to extend there Instabug***Activities, but [Android sample hosted on github.com](https://github.com/Instabug/android-sample/) says that you should extend their activities class only when you app minSdkVersion is +10.