# Cant include libruary to android studio, have duplicated with element(Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

Sorry for my english. I try include libruary [ExtendedCalendarView](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView) but in android studio i cant do this. Android studio output me errors:

```
D:\work\pc\test\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:369:9-371:85 Warning:
Element provider#com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.CalendarProvider at
AndroidManifest.xml:369:9-371:85 duplicated with element declared
at AndroidManifest.xml:312:9-314:85

D:\work\pc\test\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:31:9-38 Error:
Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/icon) from AndroidManifest.xml:31:9-38
is also present at [test:ExtendedCalendarView:unspecified]
AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to
<application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:29:5-376:19 to override.

D:\work\pc\test\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:32:9-46 Error:
Attribute application@label value=(@string/app_name_main) from AndroidManifest.xml:32:9-46
is also present at [test:ExtendedCalendarView:unspecified]  AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' 
to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:29:5-376:19 to override.

D:\work\pc\test\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:33:6-59 Error:
Attribute application@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:33:6-59
is also present at [test:ExtendedCalendarView:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-40 value=(@style/AppTheme).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to 
<application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:29:5-376:19 
to override. See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more 
information about the manifest merger.
:app:processDebugManifest FAILED
```

in Manifest i add line `tools:replace="android:icon, android:label, android:theme, android:name"`

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon, android:label, android:theme, android:name" >

        <provider
            android:name="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.CalendarProvider"
            android:authorities="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.calendarprovider" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tools: replace not replacing in Android manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/tools-replace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest)

Comment: @AbAppletic i try many way, but it not help me. And i create qestin, i saw this link, but advice not help me

Comment: What files do you have in the drawable folder? And why are you using `tools:replace`?

Comment: @AbAppletic in drawable i have standart icon file(android). In libruary manifest i have error `Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/icon) is also present at AndroidManifest.xml`... and i have error whith `app_name_mail` and `appTheme` and i add `tools:replace` this value