# Android Manifest merging failed SmartLocation library

Tags: android, location, android-manifest, build.gradle

I am trying to include [SmartLocation github library](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib/blob/master/README.md) in my project and getting so confusing errors.

**build.grade(app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.0.0' 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "project.com.selfieoffice"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile ('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.5') {
        transitive = false
    }
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

**main/AndroidManifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    package="project.com.selfieoffice">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity_">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**debug/AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    package="project.com.selfieoffice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:value" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="6587000"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
        <activity android:name="project.com.selfieoffice.activities.MainActivity_" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="io.nlopez.smartlocation.activity.providers.ActivityGooglePlayServicesProvider$ActivityRecognitionService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="io.nlopez.smartlocation.geofencing.providers.GeofencingGooglePlayServicesProvider$GeofencingService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="io.nlopez.smartlocation.geocoding.providers.AndroidGeocodingProvider$AndroidGeocodingService"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Errors:**

> /Users/zulqurnainjutt/Desktop/AndroidProjects/SelfieOffice/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>   Error:(20) No resource identifier found for attribute 'replace' in
>   package 'project.com.selfieoffice' Error:(28) No resource identifier
>   found for attribute 'replace' in package 'project.com.selfieoffice'
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/Users/zulqurnainjutt/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 1

What is wrong with this project? why can't i include smart location library.

if i do something it gives message of android manifest merging as mentioned in library page `Problems` section , is anyone using this lib can help ?

Comment: i have placed `tools:replace="android:value"` in every possible place i can to make it work , like in <meta> tag , in <application> tag , removed it from one of them , check every combination , no success

Comment: anything for me to do ?

Comment: Problem is what is right place then

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/tools-replace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem , thanks to @Dipali shah by following these steps:

- Removing `tools:replace` tags from all places of my Android manifests , debug and main both
- Replacing my `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` as `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
- Adding/replacing `<meta-data tools:replace="android:value" android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in  tag above  tag, in main Android manifest
- Check if you have google play services already there , if not then do this => Right click `app` package click `open module settings` go to `dependency` tab , click `+` and select `com.google.android.gms:play-services:xxxx` and OK.
- Clean and Rebuilt enjoy