# Android build AndroidManifest.xml error

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Try to build ionic project in android studio on Mac, error came up as follow, anyone can give some clue.

```
Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:32:5-84 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-60
```

Removed the duplicate entry still not working.

AndroidManifest.xml File.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.cordovaplugincamerapreview.CameraActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraPreviewTheme" />
        <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$NFCStateChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

Removed the entry :

New AndroidManifest.xml File.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.cordovaplugincamerapreview.CameraActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraPreviewTheme" />
        <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$NFCStateChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

New error:

```
Merging Errors: Error: Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override. android main manifest (this file), line 26
```

Comment: duplicate permission for your camera

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" /> and     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" /> you just need one to declare .

Comment: Removed the duplicated entry, error still there, but different one.  Merging Errors: Error: Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override. android main manifest (this file), line 26

Comment: what is the error Now , Have you  clean your project after removal ?

Comment: look at this One https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/tools-replace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` in your end of your xml file.

Remove any one permission of camera from Menifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You have `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` and `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />` . Remove the one not required.