# Merging Manifests Error

Tags: android, manifest

It won't let me continue. I declare a random value for `tools:value`, then it tells me I need to declare `tools:replace="android:value"`. It's just an endless loop, and I would appreciate some help...

> Merging Errors:
>
> Error: tools:replace specified at line:27 for attribute android:value,
>   but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 26
>
> Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="autoskillz.fpshackhub"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="AutoSkillz Hack Loader"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="autoskillz.fpshackhub.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="beast"
                tools:replace="android:value"/>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="autoskillz.fpshackhub.FloatingViewService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27360988/3395198

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya seems to tell you that your question has been answered in the link provided.

Comment: my certain situation has not been answered

Comment: How about we have somebody give me the quick solution to this instead of linking me to something that's kind of similar, but has nothing to do with my error.