# Flutter build failed error..androidmanifest doesn't have application tag

Tags: flutter, android-manifest

```
C:\Users\devis\AndroidStudioProjects\vitality\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:7:9-33 Error:
    Attribute application@label value=(vitality) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9-33
    is also present at [io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui:2.1.6] AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-43:19 to override.
```

this was the error^^^^

this is my androidmanifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="devisuresh.vitality">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

im confused where to add what since i dont have an application tag.

Comment: Please take a look. this might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924256/add-toolsreplace-androidlabel-to-application-element-at-androidmanifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the AndroidManifest file at the following hierarchy

> android/app/src/main

then you need to add `tools:replace="android:label` to between application tags

To elaborate :

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="xxxxx"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:label" // here it goes
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Comment: this worked but i also had to add this to the manifest tag xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"