# facing below error "tools:node" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound

Tags: android, android-layout

We are facing issue related manifest marge after changed in merged file error is:

> "The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:node" associated with an
>   element type "uses-permission" is not bound."

Why this error occur and how to solve this ?

We are trying to add line in application tag for override but not solve ,searching more all gives answer to add line in top for tools added this but also not solve.

After replace manifest with old files but also giving same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.Guru.Hwelth">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
       >
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.PaisaWasul_History"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Emer_Booking_History" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Manage_Cart_Search" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.verification.Email_Verification" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.verification.PayUMoney_CartList" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Claim_History" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Information.NoItemInternetIcon" /> <!-- Add Google Map Library -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> <!-- Google API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/logo" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.Information.Activity_Splash_Screen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.verification.Activity_ForgotPassword"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.login.LoginSimpleLight"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.login.Activity_Registration"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.verification.VerificationPhone"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.Information.Information_Stepper"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.login.Activity_MyProfile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.form.Activity_Camera"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.Information.About_Us_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.login.Activity_Change_Password" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.form.Activity_Chat" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.form.Activity_Complaint" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.form.Activity_Help" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_FAQ" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_my_Refferal_List" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Booked_AppPack" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Packages" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Select_Location_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Select_Service_Provider" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_Package_DetailView" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Manage_Cart_Product" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_Package_Invoice_Buy" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Services" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Select_ShopK_Location_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Select_ShopK_Service_Provider" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_ServiceProvider_DetailView" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Manage_cart_Service" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_Service_Invoice_Buy" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Hotel" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_Select_Location_HOTELSALON" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Salon" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_HotelService_DetailsView" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Manage_Cart_HotelService" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_HotelService_Invoice_Buy" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Salon_services" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_SalonService_DetailsView" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Manage_Cart_SalonService" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_SalonService_Invoice_Buy" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_HotelPacks" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Select_Hpack_Service_Provider" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_SalonPacks" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Select_Spack_Service_Provider" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Information.Activity_Search" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Transc_History" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_Wallet" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_wal_TotSaving" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Select_Offer_Location_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_Offer_Detail" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Manage_Cart_Offer" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_Offer_Invoice_Buy" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Extra.Activity_Upload_EHR" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Hotel_Services" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Stmt" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_PaisaWasul" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_Other" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Paisawasul_Category" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_PaisaWasul_DetailView" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.form.Activity_Flash_Paisawasul" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.form.Activity_Flash_Services" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.form.Activity_Flash_Salon" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.form.Activity_Flash_Hotel" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Lists.Activity_Cart_List" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_CART_ITEM_Invoice_Buy" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Extra.Activity_EHR_Photos" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Extra.Activity_EHR_PhotoList" />

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".activity.Information.Activity_Referral_Friends" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_HS_pack_DetailView" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Activity_View_Invoice" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Extra.EHR_FULL_IMAGE" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Extra.Add_EHR_Form" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Extra.Activity_EHRFORM_list" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Extra.Activity_OpenForm" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Extra.EHRFORM_ADD_Records" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Extra.EHRFORM_View_Records" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.login.Welcome_activity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.verification.PayUMoney" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.verification.PayUMoney_Salon" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.verification.PayUMoney_Hotel" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.verification.PayUMoney_ServiceProvider" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.verification.PayUMoney_EHR" />


        <service android:name=".services.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>

i want to detail description to solve this error in my project, and why coming this.
```

Answer (score 138):

The tool namespace needs to be explicitely declared inside your manifest header.
Add this attribute to your manifest markup :

> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

As a result your header will look like :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.Guru.Hwelth">
```

cf.
[[Tools: replace not replacing in Android manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/tools-replace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest/34079182][1])

Comment: If after doing these steps it still throws the error then: 1) move the line at the top i.e. place it before xmlns:android line. 2) `Invalidate Cache and Restart`  in Android Studio. 
Following this worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

Add the tools namespace explicitly,

```xml
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

as attribute to your manifest root element

Comment: You might be correct, but this is exactly what the other old answer do tell, for instance check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55363172/14291243) out.