# My React-Native application cannot start in emulator

Tags: react-native

My React-Native application cannot start in emulator.
help please!

c:\src\a1>npx react-native run-android
warn Package some-unsupported-package has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'some-unsupported-package\package.json'
Require stack:
- c:\src\a1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\resolveNodeModuleDir.js
- c:\src\a1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\releaseChecker\index.js
- c:\src\a1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\server\runServer.js
- c:\src\a1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\server\server.js
- c:\src\a1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
- c:\src\a1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
- c:\src\a1\node_modules\react-native\cli.js
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink " and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1010 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED
>   18 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 16 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

  > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/src/a1/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 40; The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:node" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 35s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

  > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/src/a1/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 40; The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:node" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:648:15)
at runOnAllDevices (c:\src\a1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Command.handleAction (c:\src\a1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)
```

Comment: do you edit android files ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334431/facing-below-error-toolsnode-associated-with-an-element-type-uses-permission

Comment: I did. But not solved

Comment: Solved it after the restart. Thanks for your help.