# android:exported added but still getting error Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, android-12, targetsdkversion

I have added `android:exported="true"` to my only activity in manifest but still getting below error after updating compile sdk and target sdk version to 31.I also tried rebuilding the project , invalidating cache and restart but that didn't helped

**Error-** `Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.`

### **AndroidManifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xyz.abc">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".framework.presentation.BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.xyz.presentation.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### Merged manifest error

> Other Manifest Files (Included in merge, but did not contribute any
> elements) firebase-installations:17.0.0 manifest,
> versionedparcelable:1.1.1 manifest, runtime:1.0.1 manifest,
> test:core:1.2.0 manifest, loader:1.0.0 manifest, facebook-share:11.1.0
> manifest, leakcanary:leaksentry:2.0-alpha-3 manifest,
> material-dialogs:input:3.2.1 manifest, material-icons-extended:1.0.0
> manifest, play-services-stats:17.0.0 manifest, interpolator:1.0.0
> manifest, activity-compose:1.3.1 manifest, material-ripple:1.0.0
> manifest, foundation:1.0.0 manifest, asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0
> manifest, savedstate-ktx:1.1.0 manifest,
> navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.3.5 manifest,
> firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0 manifest, animation:1.0.1 manifest,
> animation-core:1.0.1 manifest, installreferrer:1.0 manifest,
> firebase-crashlytics:18.0.0 manifest, ui:1.0.1 manifest,
> lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.3.1 manifest,
> play-services-auth-base:17.0.0 manifest, hilt-android:2.35.1 manifest,
> material-dialogs:core:3.2.1 manifest, AndroidManifest.xml navigation
> file, savedstate:1.1.0 manifest, cursoradapter:1.0.0 manifest,
> sqlite-framework:2.0.1 manifest, room-ktx:2.1.0 manifest,
> leakcanary-android-core:2.0-alpha-3 manifest, AndroidManifest.xml
> navigation file, media:1.0.0 manifest, coordinatorlayout:1.1.0
> manifest, legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 manifest,
> lifecycle-runtime:2.3.1 manifest, coil-kt:coil:1.3.1 manifest,
> ui-tooling-preview:1.0.0 manifest, facebook-core:11.1.0 manifest,
> core:1.6.0 manifest, material:1.0.0 manifest, firebase-common:20.0.0
> manifest, documentfile:1.0.0 manifest,
> lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.0-beta01 manifest,
> play-services-base:17.1.0 manifest, ui-tooling-data:1.0.0 manifest,
> coil-base:1.3.1 manifest, firebase-analytics-ktx:19.0.0 manifest,
> localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0 manifest, swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha03
> manifest, constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-beta02 manifest,
> core-ktx:1.6.0 manifest, firebase-database-collection:18.0.0 manifest,
> coil-compose-base:1.3.1 manifest, activity:1.3.1 manifest,
> AndroidManifest.xml navigation file, facebook-messenger:11.1.0
> manifest, print:1.0.0 manifest, customview:1.1.0 manifest,
> material-icons-core:1.0.0 manifest,
> play-services-measurement-sdk:19.0.0 manifest, fragment:1.3.4
> manifest, firebase-appcheck-interop:16.0.0-beta01 manifest,
> facebook-login:11.1.0 manifest, cardview:1.0.0 manifest,
> runtime-rxjava2:1.0.0 manifest, viewpager2:1.0.0 manifest,
> play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0 manifest,
> play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0 manifest,
> lifecycle-livedata-core:2.3.1 manifest, play-services-safetynet:17.0.0
> manifest, AndroidManifest.xml navigation file,
> lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1 manifest, transport-backend-cct:3.0.0
> manifest, fragment-ktx:1.2.4 manifest, appcompat:1.3.0 manifest,
> transport-runtime:3.0.0 manifest, lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.2.0
> manifest, firebase-firestore-ktx:23.0.0 manifest,
> legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 manifest, play-services-basement:17.1.1
> manifest, firebase-storage:20.0.0 manifest,
> play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0 manifest,
> leakcanary-android:2.0-alpha-3 manifest, firebase-auth-interop:20.0.0
> manifest, lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.1 manifest, browser:1.0.0 manifest,
> firebase-auth:21.0.1 manifest, material:1.2.1 manifest,
> slidingpanelayout:1.0.0 manifest, vectordrawable:1.1.0 manifest,
> recyclerview:1.1.0 manifest, play-services-auth:19.0.0 manifest,
> room-runtime:2.1.0 manifest, dagger-lint-aar:2.35.1 manifest,
> navigation-dynamic-features-runtime:2.3.5 manifest,
> play-services-measurement-api:19.0.0 manifest,
> firebase-encoders-json:18.0.0 manifest, sqlite:2.0.1 manifest,
> facebook-android-sdk:11.1.0 manifest, firebase-components:17.0.0
> manifest, transport-api:3.0.0 manifest,
> protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0 manifest, markdown-processor:0.1.3
> manifest, play-services-measurement-base:19.0.0 manifest,
> firebase-common-ktx:20.0.0 manifest, activity-ktx:1.3.1 manifest,
> firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.0.0 manifest, coil-compose:1.3.1 manifest,
> multidex:2.0.1 manifest, core-runtime:2.1.0 manifest,
> fragment-testing:1.2.0 manifest, ui-graphics:1.0.1 manifest,
> AndroidManifest.xml navigation file, ui-tooling:1.0.0 manifest,
> grpc-android:1.28.0 manifest, ui-unit:1.0.1 manifest,
> play-services-measurement:19.0.0 manifest, play:core:1.9.1 manifest,
> annotation-experimental:1.1.0 manifest,
> play-services-measurement-sdk-api:19.0.0 manifest,
> play-services-tasks:17.0.0 manifest, firebase-analytics:19.0.0
> manifest, facebook-common:11.1.0 manifest, drawerlayout:1.1.1
> manifest, AndroidManifest.xml navigation file,
> navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha09 manifest,
> facebook-gamingservices:11.1.0 manifest, firebase-firestore:23.0.0
> manifest, lifecycle-livedata:2.2.0 manifest,
> legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 manifest, test:monitor:1.2.0 manifest,
> AndroidManifest.xml navigation file, facebook-applinks:11.1.0
> manifest, viewpager:1.0.0 manifest, ui-geometry:1.0.1 manifest,
> lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1 manifest, constraintlayout:2.0.4 manifest,
> ui-text:1.0.1 manifest, AndroidManifest.xml navigation file,
> firebase-installations-interop:17.0.0 manifest, transition:1.3.0
> manifest, foundation-layout:1.0.1 manifest, appcompat-resources:1.3.1
> manifest, runtime-livedata:1.0.0 manifest, runtime-saveable:1.0.1
> manifest, firebase-measurement-connector:19.0.0 manifest,
> vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0 manifest, main nav_graph.xml navigation
> file  Merging Errors: Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly
> specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are
> required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the
> corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details. Dairy.app main manifest (this file) Error:
> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps
> targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit
> value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an
> intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details. Dairy.app main manifest (this file) Error:
> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps
> targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit
> value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an
> intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details. Dairy.app main manifest (this file)

Comment: Check your merged manifest (e.g., via the sub-tab in the manifest editor in Android Studio) to see if you have a component from a library that needs to be addressed.

Comment: @CommonsWare Merged manifest has nothng to show with same error-"Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined"

Comment: @CommonsWare If it's due to some library i believe i can't change the manifest for library activities?nd i am not using any other library except basic android libraries like jetpack compose,hilt,room,firebase etc

Comment: @CommonsWare added merged manifest complete error/logs in question.

Comment: "If it's due to some library i believe i can't change the manifest for library activities" -- you should be able to override the `android:exported` value using `tools:replace`, but you need to identify the components that need it.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper I had the same error last week, it was an android library module (without any activity inside) which was causing the problem, but I couldn't understand the reason. I wonder if it is a bug from the framework.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68554294/8583692

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To solve this error in target sdk 31-

1.First of all set target sdk to 30

2.Then go to the merged manifest

3.Find if there’s any activity, service, receiver or provider that does not have `android:exported` set.Override all those entries and set their `android:exported` to `true` or `false`.

4.set target sdk back to `31` and run project

Comment: Followed the same steps, still i'm facing the same issue in xamarin android

Comment: This is probably the wrong place but I also ended up here from a Xamarin error. I was able to resolve by setting `Exported` in my `Activity` attribute: `[Activity(..., Exported = true)]`. @Suchith

Comment: Per [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported) `exported` should be `true` if external apps will launch the activity, and `false` if not.

Comment: For anyone who wonder changing target sdk can be done in `config.xml` file by adding or modifying `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31" />` this line.

In Ionic 6, merged manifest file can be found at `/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Could we get more details on this solution? How does one "go to the merged manifest"? How do you check if there are "activity, servicer, receiver, or provider" with android:exported not set?

Answer (score 49):

`androidx.test:core` library version 1.3.0. Upgrading to version 1.4.0 fixed the issue.

Comment: It works for me. I worked with v32 of android sdk

Comment: And don't forget to update androidx.fragment:fragment-testing version if you are using anything below 1.4.0, otherwise this answer is incomplete

Comment: Good hint in right direction thanks!

Comment: Had the same issue, however, mine was caused by not bumping: `'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'` to `'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'`

Answer (score 35):

See also [android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554294/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity-apps-targeting).

Thanks to @faizy, @Android Developer I made this.

Upgrade these libraries to new versions:

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.4.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
```

I replaced `debugImplementation` with `androidTestImplementation` in these dependencies.

Press `Sync Project with Gradle Files`. Run the project (or rebuild, or run `Lint`). Probably it won't help. Then you should make this.

1. Downgrade `targetSdkVersion` to 30.

Run the project again. Probably it will compile.

In my case all needed `android:exported="true"` and `android:exported="false"` presented in `activity`, `service`, `receiver` and `provider` of merged `AndroidManifest` where `<intent-filter>` occured.

To find merged `AndroidManifest`, switch to `Project` and expand `app` module, then build > intermediates > merged_manifest > debug.

[image]

If some `android:exported` was missing, find a corresponding `AndroidManifest` and add it there.

2. Upgrade `targetSdkVersion` to 31.

Run the project again. If it won't compile, probably you should rebuild the project. As usually, Build > Rebuild Project, File >  Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and Restart.

After some time (several gradle syncs, restarts of Android Studio) it compiled.

Comment: Thank you, I just upgraded the dependencies you mentioned and boom it worked! Thanks for saving my time.

Comment: Thank you. I target to android SDK 33 now and it also works. The secret is the "androidx.test:core:1.4.0". It must be >= 1.4.0. Otherwise it will complain.

Comment: Thank you for the step-by-step to find the mergedmanifest.  Turns out it was a 3rd-party library we included.  Tip: If you run ./gradlew in the command line, the output tells you which line of the merged manifest is to blame. 
 In my case: `/data/app/vmdl487574943.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #326): leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakLauncherActivity:`

Answer (score 12):

The following in `app/build.gradle` may be the cause.

```
dependencies {
    debugImplementation androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:<1.4.0-alpha02 or lower>’
}
```

###### Solution 1

Update `fragment-testing` to `1.4.0-alpha03` or higher.

###### Solution 2

Add the following to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```xml
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name="androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm man! Actually I even found the issue by checking manifest merger tab. It  was this library during upgrade to Android 12, but wanted to make sure I was right.

Answer (score 10):

if you are using flutter , upgrading `flutter_local_notifications` to the latest version (now is 9.3.2) solved this error for me..

Answer (score 8):

In my case the problem was with a dependency that strictly uses version 1.0.0 of `androidx.test.core`, so i can't upgrade it. what i did is to add `android:exported="false"` to androidx.test.core activity in my main manifest with tools:node="merge" so it can be merged with origin manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity"
      android:exported="false"
      tools:node="merge" >
</activity>
<activity
            android:name="androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity"
       android:exported="false"
       tools:node="merge">
</activity>
```

and add the tools namespace.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Comment: This is failing for me: `Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.`

Answer (score 3):

In my case also updating library   implementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.3.0" to   implementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0" worked!

It also solved merged manifest errors.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, I add `android:exported="true"` and also `tools:node="merge"` to `AndroidManifest.xml` but however this error was appeared .
I found this is not about my project's Activates rather is about some **dependencies**, like this:

```
implementation 'com.najva.sdk:najva-android-sdk:1.3.3'
```

so check your project dependencies, you will find it surely.

Answer (score 2):

if you use ogury Ads put this in youre AndroidManifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name="io.presage.mraid.browser.ShortcutActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Presage.AdScreen"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `android { compileSdk 31`
2. It is important to use latest version of Gradle and Gradle Plugin.
3. Update your all dependencies to latest version also.

If problem still persists.

1. Go to your manifest file.
2. Click merged manifest at the bottom.

[image: Merged Manifest]

3. Check the error at the bottom right side, which dependency is causing the error.
4. Go to that particular dependency from above mentioned dependencies.

[image: Dependencies]

5. Set `android:exported="true"` or `android:exported="false"` where error was mentioned in merged manifest.

Note: Updating that dependency to the latest version will probably also fix that issue. Because in the latest versions of dependencies`exported` properties are already set.

Comment: Using the "Merged Manifest" tab is really useful indeed to identify the activity, service or receiver missing the exported attribute. In my case the problem was caused by the android-beacon-library dependency. Upgrading it to latest version fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly add the conflicting service to `Properties\AndroidManifest.xml` file, so that when it is merged in by your plugin it retains the `android:exported="true"` (or false).

```xml
<application>
    ...
    <service android:name="1234.PNFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: Updating my dependencies caused all sorts of other issues. Using this method seem to be more successful for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple, all you have to do is make sure that all of these tags are present...

```
<activity
        android:exported="true"/>

<receiver
        android:exported="true"/>

<service 
        android:exported="true"/>
```

just add  android:exported="true" to all dont change any thing
and  If you do not have any of the tags, you must add them all

Comment: it wants the name attribute

Answer (score 1):

Add these dependencies :

```
`// To use the androidx.test.core APIs
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:core:1.5.0")
// Kotlin extensions for androidx.test.core
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:core-ktx:1.5.0")`
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue originates from dependencies of project. Right click on `intent-filter` and select find usages option. Now, in all usage places check that if exported assigned value or nor. If not, assign a value (Even in cache folders for libraries). This will fix issue until cache refresh but you have identifies the libraries creating this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,

you should add `android:exported="true"` to all activities, services and receivers in the AndroidManifest.xml file as following.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">


<service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
        android:exported="true"
    >
```

and for receiver

```
<receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"

        android:exported="true"
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was to add this **tools:node="merge"** behind each **android:exported="true"** and add **xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"** property in your manifest balise.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for this one for Nativescript project. **[Tried and Tested]**

1. Search `intent-filter` in the build project directory (`./platforms`)

   [image]
2. Check if each `intent-filter` parent (activity, service, reciever..) have property `android:exported="true"`.
3. If it does not have `android:exported="true"` then copy the whole `<service/activity/reciever></service/activity/reciever>` block

   [image]

and put it into `AndroidMenifest.xml` under `App_resource` folder, update
the tag with `android:exported="true"` and again build the project.

**Should Work Now.**

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer this question because soon or later I will come back here.

The problem is everywhere in the manifest where a tag `<intent-filter>` is defined, the tag which contains it must have an attribute `android:exported="true|false"` because people in google are too lazy to make a default implementation when no value is specified.

The tags that can contain a `<intent-filter>` are: `<activity>`, `<service>`, `<receiver>` and `<provider>`. So you can go to your src/main/Manifest.xml and check if everything is well configured.

But this is not enough to assure your build is correct because the final manifest is the result of the merge of multiple manifest files. You can check the file `/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml` to see the real manifest configuration which the app was build.

Now, here is when the things starts to get dizzy. I'm working with a capacitor app through Quasar framework, so capacitor adds some defaults manifest files to the merge which does not have the correct configuration described at the beginning of this explanation.

The manifest with the issue is a firebase implementation (which I'm not using but is added by default anyways) located in the `node_modules`, so I add a `./scripts/fix_firebase.sh` script to my project to edit my `node_modules` every time I need it.

The script is the nex one:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE='../src-capacitor/node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
TO_SEARCH='<service android:name="com.getcapacitor.CapacitorFirebaseMessagingService" android:stopWithTask="false">'
REPLACEMENT='<service android:name="com.getcapacitor.CapacitorFirebaseMessagingService" android:stopWithTask="false" android:exported="true">'

if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]; then
  echo "Error: file '$FILE' does not exist." >&2
  exit 1
fi

if ! grep -q "$TO_SEARCH" "$FILE"; then
  echo "Error: search string '$TO_SEARCH' not found in '$FILE'." >&2
  exit 1
fi

sed -i "s/$TO_SEARCH/$REPLACEMENT/g" "$FILE"

echo "'$FILE' fixed."
```

Probably, as long as I keep adding more plugins, some of them will have a similar issue so I will need to add a correction to my fix script.

Answer (score 0):

If you build from the command line with `./gradlew installDebug` in your project folder, you can actually get a pretty good idea of what's wrong.

My error output:

- Failed parse during installPackageLI:
  /data/app/vmdl487574943.tmp/base.apk (at **Binary XML file line
  #326**): **leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakLauncherActivity**: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value
  for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present

If the package name (in my case leakcanary) doesn't tell you enough, the "binary XML file line #326" tells you which line in the merged manifest is offending.  You can find the merged manifest at (project path)/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/(release or debug)/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add this to app/build.gradle

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.4.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue(exact error below).

> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly
> specified for element
> <service#com.mapzen.android.lost.internal.GeofencingIntentService>.
> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an
> explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component
> has an intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.

After some self investigation I figure out, one of the dependency was causing the issue. In my case the dependency was

```
implementation 'com.airmap.airmapsdk:airmapsdk:3.0.0'
```

How did I figure out this? I commented all 3rd party dependencies. The error was gone. I started uncommenting one by one till I found out the actual culprit. It is tedious task but as the error didn't give me any sort of hint I tried this approach.

**Bottom line: if none of the answers here help then play around and figure out if any of the dependency is causing the issue.**

Answer (score -4):

These steps solve the problem:

1. `targetSdkVersion` if 31 change to 30
2. add line in AndroidManifest inside <activity `android:exported="true"` />
3. update gradle and gradle tools latest version.
4. remove fabric imports and tools.
5. clean and run