# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors | Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported`

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-manifest

I am new to java and android. And on running the emulator I am facing this merge conflict issue.

Complete Error message:

> Execution failed for task ':processDefaultsDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

> Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. main manifest (this file), line 35

Here
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.iab.omid.sampleapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<application

    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:name=".AdApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity
        android:name=".AdListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AdDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_ad_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".AdListActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.iab.omid.sampleapp.AdListActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    } 
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    google()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk 32
    flavorDimensions ""
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iab.omid.sampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1020
        versionName "1.1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        buildConfigField("String", "PARTNER_NAME", "\"com.iab.omid.sampleapp\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "VENDOR_KEY", "\"dummyVendor\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "VALIDATION_SCRIPT_URL", "\"complianceomsdk.iabtechlab.com\"")
        // This override URL will only change URLs seen in Charles proxy for Html ads
        buildConfigField("String", "VALIDATION_SCRIPT_URL_OVERRIDE", "\"complianceomsdk.iabtechlab.com\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "VERIFICATION_URL", "\"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/omsdk-files/compliance-js/omid-validation-verification-script-v1.js\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "VERIFICATION_PARAMETERS", "\"http://omid-android-reference-app/sendMessage?msg=\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "HTML_DISPLAY_AD", "\"https://omsdk-files.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/creatives/html_display_creative.html\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "HTML_VIDEO_AD", "\"https://omsdk-files.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/creatives/html_video_creative.html\"")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaults {

        }

        instrumentationTest {
            buildConfigField("String", "VERIFICATION_URL", "\"https://omsdk-files.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/fullstack/fullstack-verification-script.js\"")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: '../')
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.5', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.8'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:4.3.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}

task downloadOMSDKJS(type:Exec) {
    if (!file('./src/main/res/raw/omsdk_v1.js').exists()) {
        workingDir '../'
        commandLine 'sh', './scripts/download-omsdk-js.sh'
    } else {
        // We need a dummy execCommand here.
        commandLine 'sh'
    }
}

preBuild.dependsOn downloadOMSDKJS
```

I have already tried many other solutions available on StackOverflow but still haven't made any progress.

Please let me know if any more details are required to be shared to solve this in a comment.

Comment: Did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69287478/androidexported-added-but-still-getting-error-apps-targeting-android-12-and-hig

Comment: Yes, tried that. No luck. Just for reference as per the accepted solution of your link @AmmarAbdullah , whenever I am lowing the targetSdkVersion to 30, the Gradle build itself fails. Only for targetSdkVersion 32, my build is successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your libraries are defining probably an "intent_filter" on an activity

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
```

If your application is targeting API 31+, the attribute "exported" is mandatory.

So as the developer of that library didn't target API 31, the exported flag what not mandatory on his side. And he built it without exported attribute.

So what you can do, is redefine that specific class on your manifest to declare it explicitly exported or not. For example :

```
<activity android:name="com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity"
         android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ahmed. I can open the app using the emulator now. But there are 43 wanings also coming up with this.  `warning: [deprecation] ExtractorMediaSource in com.google.android.exoplayer2.source has been deprecated
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;`
                                           ^
Let me know if by any chance you can help me to solve these warnings also.

Comment: I suggest you to check the following link : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12 . It shows all the behavior changes the time you start targeting Android API 31. If there is any deprecation out of this scope, you may find it in the related library documentation or maybe on an existing solved issue.