# Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported`

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for]

android:exported="true" but it not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manifest merger failed with multiple errors | Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for \`android:exported\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71673385/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-android-12-and-higher-are-required)

Comment: You have to add it to any service you have

Comment: If you have followed the steps in the answers linked above and it still isn't working, please post your complete `AndroidManifest.xml` here as text, *not as a screenshot*.

Comment: I can suggest two things: 1. add full text code of you AndroidManifest.xml to the question. 2. Try to reload Android Studio with cache cleaning, on your screenshot everything looks good enough for workable code.