# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

I am developing new android app when I run the project I am getting following errors
Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

```
C:\Users\Edgar\AndroidStudioProjects\CreditScore\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
C:\Users\Edgar\AndroidStudioProjects\CreditScore\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
C:\Users\Edgar\AndroidStudioProjects\CreditScore\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

below my Android Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.yodgorbek.creditscore">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".MyScoreApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CreditScore">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

what I have tried tools:node="merge" and other suggestions from  folllowing link [android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554294/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity-apps-targeting)
I want to know where I am making mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by decreasing minsdk to 30