# `android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>` even though I have specified it

Tags: android, android-studio, dji-sdk

I am trying out the DJI SDK and am following [this tutorial](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration) on how to integrate the SDK into the Android Studio project I have created. I've replicated everything down to the name of the files, with the only difference being that I added the needed import statements in `MainActivity.java`.

I get the following error when I try to build the project:

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
[path to projects]\AndroidStudioProjects\ImportSDKDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I am unsure of how to fix it. One solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045327/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity-apps-targeting) was to reduce `minSdk`, but my `minSdk` attribute is already set to 19.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The codes for `MApplication.java` and `MainActivity.java` can be found in [this tutorial](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration). Here are some of the other files:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dji.importSDKDemo">
    <!-- Permissions and features -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".MApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ImportSDKDemo">
        <!-- DJI SDK -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.dji.sdk.API_KEY"
            android:value="f114adf2dd1d12a008e3184d" />
        <activity
            android:name="dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJIAoaControllerActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
        </activity>
        <service android:name="dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJIGlobalService">
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dji.importSDKDemo"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjifs_jni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libsfjni.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation ('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.12')
    compileOnly ('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.12')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to `android:exported="true"`

The post [android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68648841/295004) also mention needing `tools:node="merge"` or possibly `tools:node="replace"`

See Android Documentation regarding [Inspect the merged manifest and find conflicts](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts)

I also believe you need `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` property in your `manifest` XML tag as stated in [merge rule markers](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#merge_rule_markers)

Comment: I was gonna post a self-answer with this, thanks for your help once again!

Answer (score 0):

android:exported needs to be set for the activity with an intent filter

Comment: Just edited my code because I realised one of my <activity> tags doesn't have that attribute (of the two of them). I fixed that and the error persists.

Comment: So yeah, even though it has been set, I still get this error. I tried cleaning project and rebuilding, and it doesn't work. This answer didn't quite help me.