# Android Studio, updating build.gradle TargetSdkVersion 31 issues

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, android-manifest

We are using targetSdkVersion 30, I am trying to update it to 31

When I set targetSdkVersion to 31, I am unable to run/compile the app because it is failing build error in manifest.xml saying

> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps
> targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit
> value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an
> intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details. src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

I checked my manifest file, I added  **android:exported = true/false** for every activity , receiver!

I do not have issue if I set targeted SDK version to 30, but 31
and I am sure I added android:exported to all applicable components in manifest

please help me

Comment: Go to `AndroiManifest.xml`, click on the `Merged Manifest` at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you @DarShan You saved my time! I fount issue is in one of my libraries

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update all libraries in build.gradle file if haven't already. There's a big chance that one of them is causing this. If this isn't the case, you would have to manually check the Merged Manifest as mentioned by @DarShan.
It happened to me few days ago as well.

Comment: Thank you @DarShan You saved my time! I fount issue is in one of my libraries

Answer (score 0):

For your flutter project,
Go to: `*your_project*/android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" //add this line
    package="com.example.***your_app_name***">
```

Search for the entry of the type `activity` within `application` in the same `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
        <application
            android:name="${applicationName}"
            ...
            ...
            
    
            <meta-data 
              ...
              ... />
    
            <meta-data
              ...
              ... />
    
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"    //add this line
                tools:node="merge"         //add this line
                android:launchMode=
                ...
                ...
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In windows/user/.gradle

Delete .gradle, delete the folder

2. Reopen Android studio and change in project structure/grandle
   Change the version of the grandle
3. In the project build.gradle update the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, it's the libraries in your gradle file. This is how I solved it.

1. Comment out one library in your gradle file, clean project and rebuild project.
2. If it shows the same error, uncomment it, and repeat step 1.
3. Do this for each library and eventually, you will find that the error will change or the build will be successful.
4. When that happens, that last library that you commented is the problem. Try updating that library or using a different one.