# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter,

Tags: flutter

Hi can anyone help me I just follow the instruction here: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

but still I am getting the same error " You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported"

when uploading the file to google play consule App bundles release

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.HatidRider.app"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:name=".App"
    tools:replace="android:label"
    android:label="Hatid-PH Delivery"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCaCSJ0BZItSyXqBv8vpD1N4WBffJeKhLQ"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <service
        android:name="com.HatidRider.app.BackgroundService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.HatidRider.app"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an 
     android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate 
     method.
 In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
 additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
 FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:name=".App"
    tools:replace="android:label"
    android:label="Hatid-PH Delivery"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCaCSJ0BZItSyXqBv8vpD1N4WBffJeKhLQ"/>

<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
         the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
         while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
         to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
    <meta-data
      android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
      android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
      />
    <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
         Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
         screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
         gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
         Flutter's first frame. -->
    <meta-data
      android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
      android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
      />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
     This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
<service
    android:name="com.HatidRider.app.BackgroundService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" />
<meta-data
    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
    android:value="2" />
```

Check if it works now, I have explicity set `android:exported = "true"`
as you have `launcher` and in other places

Comment: Hi I try it both ways but still getting the error

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70531623/9520315

Comment: hi where can I find the merge manifest in latest android studio is it not showing on the buttom part thank you for the help <3

Comment: please see image: https://ibb.co/bmv21yW

Comment: You have to add `android:exported = 'true'` under `android:name` within the activity tag

Comment: ok I will try to this one

Comment: I put it inside the <activity></activity> tag under the android:name still the problem accure

Comment: still haven't resolve the issue

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: still the same nothing change

Comment: I already Updated the build.gradle 

compileSdkVersion 31
targetSdkVersion 31

also the project structure to Android API 31

Comment: I hope there is someone know this issue better T.T

Comment: Check if it works now and if it didn't work then refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554294/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity-apps-targeting

Comment: I will try to rebuild and reupload the build file thanks guys

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72368059/8253662