# Google play error: You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver - 'android:exported'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, onesignal

Issue : **You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported**

When I loaded my aab file to google play I got this error. I understood it, but when I changed my manifest files (C:\android\App\Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml and C:\android\App\Assets\Plugins\Android\OneSignalConfig.plugin\AndroidManifest.xml) I got same error.

It happened, because OneSignal has additional lines, when I don't see in C:\android\App\Assets\Plugins\Android\OneSignalConfig.plugin\AndroidManifest.xml file. Also I can't modified final AndroidManifest.xml file, because Unity starts auto-assembly of the application.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for it, but it's not right, because you can change AndroidManifest.xml files other libs. But, if you don't have any solution you can use this.

*Yes, you can cahnge your Target API level to 30 API, but after november 2022 your apps will be hidden from the store and I think, it's not solution for this trable ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695372/you-uploaded-an-apk-or-android-app-bundle-which-has-an-activity-activity-alias))*

1. Go to {YOUR_UNITY_PROJECT}\Assets\Plugins\Android\ and open AndroidManifest.xml file and added android:expodted="true" ([more](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity-arf/android-12-build))
2. Open all dirs and check other AndroidManifest.xml files. If activities, receivers, services without android:exported tag - add it.
3. Save all changed
4. Start build your app
5. Go to {YOUR_UNITY_PROJECT}\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release and open AndroidManifest.xml
6. Find all activities, receivers, services without android:exported tag. If you don't have this items - you can load your file to google play. If you have - go to step 7.
7. Go to C:\Users{YOUR_USER}.gradle\caches\ and search required libraries.
8. Open libs and change AndroidManifest.xml files (add android:exported tag with false or true). I added false value (android:exported="false")
9. Save all changed and go to step 4.

For example: I have oneSignal lib, and I have some services without exproted tag. I founded this lib (C:\Users\AGENTxXx.gradle\caches\transforms-3\98a2faf5d9f43588b86ab05e1221a233\transformed\jetified-onesignal-unity), changed AndroidManifest.xml and build my aab file again.