# Element receiver#nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent at AndroidManifest.xml:36:9-40 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Element receiver#nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent at AndroidManifest.xml:36:9-40:20 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-16:20

When I'm generating the Signed Bundle in Android Studio, Please help me with this, any one.....

Answer (score 2):

If your project is Cordova project, you have to update plugin cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing.
Run this scripts:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
```

Try to build your project again. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending if they've updated the library correctly or not, you can just add the line android:exported="true" to the manifest file. Sometimes libraries update slowly over a versions release.

It is to do with the migration to Android 12 and API version 31. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported

An easy way to see all the issues to do with this part of the migration, used merged manifest found in this answer.

[You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'an](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695372/you-uploaded-an-apk-or-android-app-bundle-which-has-an-activity-activity-alias)

[image]