# uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter,

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

I am using React Native .

Got this error and updated as the android documentation suggests but still receiving the same.

In my case I have two android Manifest and have added **android:export="true"** to all AndroidManifest was still getting error

So as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70957174  to dowload and install an emulator with android 12 to get places am yet to add android:exported can be viewed but

and am receiving this error

```
 Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1381469782.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #216):
com.wix.reactnativenotifications.fcm.FcmInstanceIdListenerService:
```

```
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present
```

I have made changes in both visible AndroidManifest.xml but according to this log am yet to add android:exported

Answer (score 0):

Did you added android:exported="true"  inside action like this in your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
    <application
  .... >
  <activity
  ...
    android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: yes I have added all of them to all activity , sender and receivers. can this happen due to some due to some mismatching or incompatible configuration in gradle file.