# Hi guys! Why google does not accepting my abb file?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-12

Google does not accept my abb file " **You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported** " Everywhere says add " **android:exported="true"** " for them it works, but mine does not work for some reason. My Unity version is 2021.3.9f1 and Android studio 2021.2.1 patch 2. What could be the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

**This is my android manifest**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.unity3d.player" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
      <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:extractNativeLibs="true" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
          tools:targetApi="m">
        <!-- The MessagingUnityPlayerActivity is a class that extends
             UnityPlayerActivity to work around a known issue when receiving
             notification data payloads in the background. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            tools:targetApi="n"
            android:exported="true">
    
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
    
          <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
          <meta-data android:name="android.notch_support" android:value="true" />
    
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
        </service>
    
        <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
        <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
        <meta-data android:name="unity.launch-fullscreen" android:value="True" />
        <meta-data android:name="unity.allow-resizable-window" android:value="False" />
        <meta-data android:name="notch.config" android:value="portrait|landscape" />
      </application>
      <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
          tools:ignore="ManifestOrder" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
    </manifest>
```

No error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9kyo.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695372/you-uploaded-an-apk-or-android-app-bundle-which-has-an-activity-activity-alias) answer your questions? There are more steps in case adding a single line doesn't help.