# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. unity
Version unity 2021.1.19 all that is with this error does not help anything. Please help!!

Version unity 2021.1.19 all that is with this error does not help anything. Please help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'an](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695372/you-uploaded-an-apk-or-android-app-bundle-which-has-an-activity-activity-alias)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:exported="true"` or `android:exported="false"` to the activities, services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Note: if the App component includes the LAUNCHER category, set android:exported to true otherwise set android:exported to false.

Comment: Thanks, but I did these manipulations. Unity update helped