# Getting issue while upload bundle in play store. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher

Tags: react-native

Iam getting the below issue while uploading the bundle to play store.

**You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported**

I have added **android:exported="true"** for all the required activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter (include all node modules android manifest file also). But still iam getting same issue. So please let me know what can i do resolve this issue

Manifest file.

`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.test.dummy">
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--  <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity> -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
                android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
                    android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
        <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground (remote-only, for local use ignoreInForeground) -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="true"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@color/white"/>
        <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service> -->
        <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver"/>
        <receiver 
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.BackgroundAction"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionsService"/>
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService"/>
    </application>
    <queries>
        <intent>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START"/>
        </intent>
         <intent>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <data android:scheme="http" />
      </intent>
      <intent>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <data android:scheme="https" />
      </intent>
        </queries>
</manifest>
```

`

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71012349/8196025)?

Comment: yes, I have added android:exported="true" in all the required places. I have attached my manifest file also. please check and let me know if I missed anything. @RohitAggarwal