# Play Store reject while upload file .aab You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

[image]I already added << `android:exported="true"`>> on `AndroidMainifest.xml` file, but it's still show error: You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without `'android:exported'` property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: [developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)

Here sample code on AndroidMainifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:node="merge"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Thank you and waiting for your help.

Comment: android:exported="true"/"false" add this paramaters all activity ,service, recevers android 12 changes

Comment: I already added android:exported="true" to all activity that inside has intent-filter and rebuild & re-upload many times but it's still show the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695372/you-uploaded-an-apk-or-android-app-bundle-which-has-an-activity-activity-alias

Comment: I follow the document that mention on error 'https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported' but it's still not solve.

Comment: As I check the stackoverflow link above It's the same what do before.

Comment: share here your full manifeast screen shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250080/discussion-between-anand-alabal-and-sreng-bona).

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by added `android:exported="true"` to all activity, service,... that have `intent-filter` inside on `androidMainifest.xml` included file libraries also need to add `android:exported="true"`.

Possible search for all `<intent-filter>` then select `scope` tag (if you use android studio IDE) then add `android:exported="true"` to all activity, service,... that have `intent-filter` inside.