# uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher

Tags: flutter, apk, store

i have problem in mu flutter app

when i upload AAB file to google store this error i had

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

my flutter version 1.22.0 but added  android:exported to activity in manifest file and the argetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 31  but still the same problem

my flutter version 1.22.0 but added  android:exported to activity in manifest file and the argetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 31  but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to my manifest:

```
android:exported="true"
```

If it didn't work please take a look at this:
[Click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695372/you-uploaded-an-apk-or-android-app-bundle-which-has-an-activity-activity-alias)