# Gradle Build error when trying to generate a signed bundle or APK due to errors in Android Manifest

Tags: android, gradle, build

I am working on a version of an Android app and I would like to release a new update. The app compiles well, but when I try to generate a release apk or bundle, I always get the same Gradle errors that I cannot solve, as I don´t understand the problem. I have been wrapping my head around this for days, so I would be thankful for any help or hints.

This is the error log of the failing gradle task:

```
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest
/Users/dwa2112/Development/Template/Template/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:31:5-235:19 Warning:
    application@android:icon was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:31 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
/Users/dwa2112/Development/Template/Template/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:57:9-67:20 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
/Users/dwa2112/Development/Template/Template/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:109:9-114:20 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
/Users/dwa2112/Development/Template/Template/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:115:9-119:20 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

This is my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sherdle.universal">

    <!-- Always Required to get content and check if internet is available -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Always Required for image coaching & maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Required for notifications & radio -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- Required for maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Required for visualizer & radio -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <!-- Required for tumblr -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <!-- Required for in-app purchases -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <!-- Activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
            tools:node="merge" />
        <activity
            android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
            tools:node="merge" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedActivityHMS"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.CanPostThis2.SplashTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme"
            tools:node="merge" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.CanPostThis2.SplashTheme"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".picer_lib.activity.ImagePickActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/vw_FilePickerTheme"
            tools:node="merge" />


        <activity
            android:name=".picer_lib.activity.ImageBrowserActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/vw_FilePickerTheme"
            tools:node="merge" />

        <service
            android:name=".Fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".Fcm.GCMRegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".picer_lib.activity.VideoPickActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/vw_FilePickerTheme"
            tools:node="merge" />

        <activity
            android:name=".picer_lib.activity.AudioPickActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/vw_FilePickerTheme"
            tools:node="merge" />

        <activity
            android:name=".picer_lib.activity.NormalFilePickActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/vw_FilePickerTheme"
            tools:node="merge" />

        <activity android:name=".providers.rss.ui.RssDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".providers.videos.ui.VideoDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".providers.wordpress.ui.WordpressDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".providers.woocommerce.ui.ProductActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".comments.CommentsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HolderActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".attachmentviewer.ui.AttachmentActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".attachmentviewer.ui.AudioPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".attachmentviewer.ui.VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".providers.woocommerce.ui.CheckoutActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".providers.woocommerce.ui.WooCommerceLoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".providers.videos.player.YouTubePlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />


        <!-- Services -->
        <service
            android:name=".providers.audio.player.player.PlaybackService"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge" />
        <service android:name=".providers.radio.player.RadioService" />
        <service android:name=".attachmentviewer.MusicService" />

        <!--
        A receiver that will receive media buttons and send as
        intents to your MediaBrowserServiceCompat implementation.
        Required on pre-Lollipop. More information at
        http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".providers.audio.player.media.MediaSessionReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--<receiver android:name=".providers.soundcloud.player.player.PlayerReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>-->

        <!-- Meta Data -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
            android:exported="true"
            android:value="DISABLE"
            tools:node="merge" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:exported="true"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"
            tools:node="merge" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:exported="true"
            android:value="true"
            tools:node="merge" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="remove" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.jaredsburrows:gradle-license-plugin:0.8.80'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.14.0'

    }
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext {
    supportlib_version = '29.0.0'
    gps_version = '[16.0.0, 17.0.0)'
    fb_version = '[16.0.0, 18.0.0)'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle for the module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jaredsburrows.license'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

/*
 * To update licenses, run:
 * - cd [project location]
 * - ./gradlew licenseReleaseReport
 */
licenseReport {
    generateHtmlReport = true
    generateJsonReport = false

    // These options are ignored for Java projects
    copyHtmlReportToAssets = true
    copyJsonReportToAssets = false
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.webagenten.canpostthis"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 12
        versionName "7.0"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
        }

        //Optionally configure your OneSignal IDs below
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("")
            storePassword ""
            keyAlias ""
            keyPassword ""
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
            variant.mergeAssets.doLast {
                delete(fileTree(dir: variant.mergeAssets.outputDir, includes: ['x86/ffmpeg', '**/*.ffmpeg']))
            }
        }
        variant.getRuntimeConfiguration().exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
    }
}


repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.3.0' //TV
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.2' //TV & Radio
    implementation 'com.cleveroad:audiovisualization:1.0.1' //Radio
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9' //WC
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1' //WC
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    // Faceook SDK
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:[4,5)'


    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.13.0, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.duolingo.open:rtl-viewpager:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ed-george:AndroidVimeoExtractor:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex-instrumentation:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.2"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.1'
    implementation('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828') {
        exclude group: "com.github.vansikrishna:Multimager:1.0.8", module: "jetified-Multimager-1.0.8-runtime"
    }

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.duolingo.open:rtl-viewpager:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ed-george:AndroidVimeoExtractor:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex-instrumentation:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation project(path: ':imagepicker')
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.4.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:5.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.5'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.5'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.vansikrishna:Multimager:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.4.0'
    implementation 'mobi.upod:time-duration-picker:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.2.2.LTS'
    implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.2.2.LTS'

}
```

I would appreciate any hints or help, as I simply don´t understand what´s wrong here, as the mentioned receivers in the error log are simply not part of the manifest.

Comment: Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70531623/9520315

Comment: Have you tried to remove the entry `tools:replace="android:icon"`?