# adb: failed to install

Tags: android, flutter

Hello while trying to run my Flutter Application on Real Android device im getting following error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM G973F in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/name/Desktop/project/application/poi/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting certificates for /data/app/vmdl639070508.tmp/base.apk: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl639070508.tmp/base.apk using APK Signature Scheme v2: SHA-256 digest of contents did not verify]
Error launching application on SM T500.
```

I tried :
updating android studio
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
.....

But found no solution yet
Hope anyone can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554294/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity-apps-targeting)

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 Hey I did and now updated code getting different error please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest, add `android:exported="true"`.

example:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.packssas.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Hey I did and now updated code getting different error please check

Answer (score 0):

Only increase the storage size of your device

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXWs7.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32753869)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Available Storage in the machine you are developing with, you might face this issue if you are running in low storage.

Another solution is actually a dummy one, but it works, which is to restart your machine.

Comment: i have 60GB free and still getting the issue.