# Manifest merger failed in push notification

Tags: react-native, android-manifest, android-12

I use native push notification in react and getting this error:

> Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
>
> Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>
> D:\F Drive\Sayalani React\React Native\basicgui\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.basicgui">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
        <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="false"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554294/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity-apps-targeting)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear:

> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting
> Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for
> android:exported when the corresponding component has an intent filter
> defined

In your manifest file, there are several receivers that do not have the ***exported*** property:

```
<receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a day to find the solution of this error, I checked **activity, service, receiver** in whole project but nothing wrong were found, and decided to install all packages separately (in new clean project with RN version you need) testing build every time I added a new package and found out that my **react-native-onesignal** has an **old version** that breaks build;

So I installed new version and problem was resolved