# can't push my flutter app to playstore becuase of "intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set" error

Tags: android, flutter

I try everything to solve this error, any solutions please ? the manifest.xml file is down.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.zroom"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<queries>
    <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app makes calls -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app sends emails -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
<!-- For Ios -->
<!--<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
</array>-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <!-- Add this -->
<application
    tools:replace="android:label"
    android:label="Zroom"
    android:exported="true"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with https://YOUR_HOST -->
            <data

                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="meet.zroom.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

the problem keeps occur even I updated flutter to the latest version as well as all packages as you can see:

```
dependencies:
```

flutter:
sdk: flutter
intl: ^0.17.0
jitsi_meet: ^4.0.0
shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
uni_links: ^0.5.1
flutter_inset_box_shadow: ^1.0.7
url_launcher:
http: ^0.13.4
universal_html: ^2.0.0
html: ^0.15.0
animations: ^2.0.0

## The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

## Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0
flutter_native_splash: ^2.0.1+1

flutter_native_splash:
color: "#ffffff"
image: assets/images/logosmall.png

flutter_icons:
android: true
ios: true
image_path: "assets/images/logosmallx.png"

Comment: The solution is explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68648841/6003002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the jitsi_meet flutter package which doesn't support target sdk = 31. So i used an alternative package which is jitsi_meet_wrapper and eveything is fine.