# Error: The method isn't defined for the class in Flutter and Module was compiled with an icompatible version

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I was just trying out a source code that I have seen online, and I wanted to test it, however, it is giving me multiple errors because of the new update on widgets.

**The source code that I am trying to run and execute is:** https://github.com/themaaz32/phone_verification

**The errors being displayed when I run the application are the following:**

```
lib/screens/login_screen.dart:52:12: Error: The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the class 'ScaffoldState'.
 - 'ScaffoldState' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'showSnackBar'.
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(e.message)));
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/screens/login_screen.dart:69:9: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class '_LoginScreenState'.
 - '_LoginScreenState' is from 'package:phone_verification/screens/login_screen.dart' ('lib/screens/login_screen.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
        FlatButton(
        ^^^^^^^^^^
lib/screens/login_screen.dart:87:43: Error: The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the class 'ScaffoldState'.
 - 'ScaffoldState' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'showSnackBar'.
                _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/screens/login_screen.dart:122:9: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class '_LoginScreenState'.
 - '_LoginScreenState' is from 'package:phone_verification/screens/login_screen.dart' ('lib/screens/login_screen.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
        FlatButton(
        ^^^^^^^^^
```

**New Errors**
[image: Error for running the app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your version of Flutter is newer than that of the library. The library still uses `FlatButton` for example which [was removed as a breaking change](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context)

Replace every `FlatButton` with `TextButton` and for showing a SnackBar you can use:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Comment: which part should I change in the SnackBar?

Comment: AFAIK you don't need to change `SnackBar`. If you still get an error, please share the error message.

Comment: snackbar is okay already, but it says  Error: No named parameter with the name 'color'. for TextButton

Comment: The widgets are already resolved, however I am still getting errors whihc I will attach above. pls help

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67801441/16463801).

Comment: New error occured: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> org/gradle/api/services/BuildService

Comment: That is shown after I tried changing the kotlin version

Comment: ERROR:  Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin-android']
   > The current Gradle version 5.6.2 is not compatible with the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use Gradle 6.1.1 or newer, or the previous version of the Kotlin plugin.

Comment: Yes you also have to update the gradle version if you update the kotlin version. I usually init a new empty project or have a look at the latest flutter examples in github to see the versions i need. You can try kotlin: 1.6.10 and gradle:7.1.2.

Comment: I have eliminated the above errors in whichI hae upgraded kotlin and gradle but I still get an error..  Dependency 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 31 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-29'

Comment: I just want to execute and try the source code :(

Comment: Go to android/app/build.gradle and change the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 31 or something above.

Comment: New error.. * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.easyapproach.phone_verification.MainActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.

Comment: Go to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and add `android:exported` inside the `<application>` tag beneath `android:icon` for example. If this doesn't help (what I assume) then your library didn't set the `android:exported` flag. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68648841/16463801) then.

Comment: It has successfully run, however, the OTP is not being sent to the emulator, is there anything I should do with firebase or something? or it should work? After putting my number, it loads like forever

Comment: I can't help you there without any code. But this is off-topic, so please open another question. If this answer helped you, then please accept and upvote it.

Comment: the code is in te github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to import material.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```