# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs in Android Studioo

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-manifest, manifest-merging

So, I am a beginner into Android and Kotlin. I just began learning. While I was experimenting with Intent today, I incurred an error.

`Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

I found some solutions here and tried to implement them, but it did not work.

This is my build.gradle :

`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chattery"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
}
```

`

This is my AndroidManifest :

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chattery">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".commons.ChatteryApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ui.activities.ChatActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityActionBarTheme"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.activities.MainActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.activities.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/LoginTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.SignUpActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.activities.WelcomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityActionBarTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.activities.WelcomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityActionBarTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.UsersActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityActionBarTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.activities.ProfileActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.chattery.NOTIFICATION_TARGET" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />

        <service
            android:name=".firebase.MessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`

This is my Merging Errors :

```
Merging Errors: 
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.example.chattery.ui.activities.MainActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. Chattery.app main manifest (this file), line 23 Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.example.chattery.ui.activities.ProfileActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. Chattery.app main manifest (this file), line 46
```

This is my first week with coding, I am sorry if this is a really silly thing. I am really new to this and did not find any other place to ask. Sorry if I broke any rules

Comment: Try to turn on `merged manifest` mode for manifest xml in your android studio. So you can see logs about errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554294/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity-apps-targeting)

Answer (score 0):

### Error Message

As the error message suggests you might want to add `android:exported` to your activity definition. It also informs you about the fact, that this is only the case for [targetSdk](https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk#why-target) >= 31. So another solution would be to lower you targetSdk. But that would come with some feature tradeoffs. I wouldn't recommend that.

### Solution 1 (Recommended)

According to this statement [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20export%20your%20app%27s%20components%20unnecessarily.%20For%20example%2C%20if%20you%20intend%20to%20launch%20an%20app%20component%20using%20an%20internal%20nested%20intent%2C%20set%20that%20component%27s%20android%3Aexported%20attribute%20to%20false.). Google suggests not setting this property unnecessarily to `true`

So the simplest solution would be to change this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To this:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity" android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Notice the added `android:exported` attribute.

### Solution 2 (Not Recommended)

In your module level `gradle.build` you have somewhere at the top the property `targetSdk`. Change the value to something lower than `31` eg. `30` which corresponds to `Android 11`. Mind that you need to download the required target sdk via the sdk manager. Otherwise you won't be able to compile your app anymore

Answer (score 0):

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'