# I have this problem in flutter .........>

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for
> element <activity#com.example.flutter_application_1.MainActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

I'm creating an app with flutter, after I linked it to firebase, this problem appeared when I tried to run the app on the emulator

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/q/68554294/10157127

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.