# What causes the Build Failed error in AndroidManifest.xml and how can I fix it in my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I was working on this project until today when it showed this issue.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

[image]

**this is my AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lekwacious.shopping_app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <application
        android:label="shopping_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="AIzaSyDjHSDTbzDMdMba04MgSMb5dfmwVsh2gII"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Could someone kindly explain this issue to me and let me know how to fix it?

Comment: This is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. compileSdkVersion 33 (builde.gradle app)
2. ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' (build gradle)
3. classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2' (build gradle)
4. distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip (gradle-wrapper.properties)