# Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]im doing flutter app and i have change targetSdkVersion 30 to 31 after that it through some error
Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined
and i give one solution for the error
android:exported="true"
after that also it showing same error

## [image: The below images are shown my proplem kindly someone help me pleae]

Comment: Please do not post terminal text output in a screen shot. Instead just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68554294/150978

Answer (score -2):

Please add `android:exported="true"` in manifest file

[image: Please add android:exported="true" in manifest file]

Comment: i have added the line in manifest file after that also im getting same error