# Solve this : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value

Tags: android, flutter-dependencies

Launching lib/main.dart on CPH2473 in debug mode...
/Users/mac/Desktop/motivationalmode/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-22:20 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

how to fixed this error Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

Comment: Does this previous Question / Answer help: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554294/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity-apps-targeting?rq=2)?

Comment: Please take a look on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

from now on after android 11 , every activity or service has to specify android:exported, Usage : it is used to link other package activity to your app activity. By linking an other app can open your app or specified activity.

In your case you might be using an old Library or Code where exported is not Defined.

Add this line in your .xml file if it contains any activity or service.

```
<activity
android:name=".activity_name"
android:exported = "true" />
```