# Must remove QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission but cannot find it

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

Google Play Console (*App Content* section) declares that my published app makes use of

```
android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES
```

and I want to remove this permission.

I checked my *AndroidManifest.xml* and the *Merged Manifest* but I cannot find it.

Where should I look at to find all permissions included by dependencies, libraries, ecc.?
Thank you.

Comment: you can follow my answer in another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/75424854/6748623

Answer (score 10):

I didn't find exactly where this permission was requested, but there is a simple way to remove it definitely: add this to ***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: How did you update the app content to remove the permission from the declaration?

Comment: I uploaded a new version to the Google Play Store

Comment: @mdicosimo does Playstore able to approve your latest version?

Comment: Yes, it seems so... 

Comment: @mdicosimo is it approved? Please let me know. I will also try this solution after that.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Google Playstore declined my release.

Comment: Just a note, when doing this you also need to make sure xlmns:tools is declared in your manifest header or else you may get an error like I did. Explained more in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334431/facing-below-error-toolsnode-associated-with-an-element-type-uses-permission

Comment: I tried too, this solution not works at all. my app get rejected again.

Comment: if you are trying to replace a track in production, you need to change the gradual release to 100%. Only then your version is approved

Answer (score 1):

Also remember to check if in the alpha, beta, etc. tests. upload update that no longer has sensitive permissions.
https://bapspatil.medium.com/dear-googles-permissions-declaration-form-can-we-break-up-85bc6b62f690

Comment: you should check in imported library in your projects gradles files

Answer (score -8):

You can find it in manifest with all other permissions and from there you can remove the line.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: Where? AndroidManifest.xml doesn't contain this line. I also verified "Merged Manifest"