# Google Play Services are randomly adding AD ID permission into my Manifest

Tags: android, firebase

I just found out that my Google Play Services are adding into merged manifest AD permission and for that reason I cant upload app to my playstore because it requires reasoning why I want ads in my app (I don't).

These are my gradle libraries:

```
//Google SDK
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.0.3'

    //GCM for internet connection monitoring
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'

    //GooglePay
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.1.0'

    //Google Firebase SDK - Crashlytics, Firebase Messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.13') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.8'
```

This is merged manifest:
[image]

It seems like its google analytics (firebase). But I don't want and don't use any ad content in my app so I don't understand why is Google adding this stuff into my app without my approval.

I just tried to do this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1' {
        exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
        exclude module: "play-services-measurement"
        exclude module: "play-services-measurement-sdk"
  }
```

as I found out but its not even compiling (got GradleScriptException):

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1() for arguments [build_ballt3q1t2mmz35mzah3ugy17$_run_closure2$_closure23@69dcec81] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

Comment: This seems to be the same problem faced here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74127836/your-manifest-file-doesnt-include-the-com-google-android-gms-permission-ad-id-p