# Flutter Plugin Issue image_cropper and images_picker

Tags: flutter-dependencies

How to use all Plugin together.

```
image_cropper: ^1.4.1
image_picker: ^0.8.2
images_picker: ^1.2.0
```

Something wrong in AndroidManifest.xml:49:17-73 Error:

```
D:\imagepiker\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:49:17-73 Error: 
        Attribute activity#com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity@theme value=(@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:49:17-73
        is also present at [com.github.LuckSiege.PictureSelector:picture_library:v2.6.1] AndroidManifest.xml:66:13-58 value=(@style/Base.Theme.NoActionBar).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the suggestion?

Comment: I try this Suggestion but it also not worked

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 56; The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:replace" associated with an element type "activity" is not bound.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/tools-replace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest)

Comment: It does not work for some reason.... I try to add tools:replace="android:icon, android:label,android:theme" to application but it does not work

Comment: Actually Issue occurs, when I adding the "images_picker: ^1.2.0 " this Plugin