# 'tools:replace="android:exported"' to <receiver> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override

Tags: java, android, flutter, replace, setuptools

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\Emart_V2.1_Source_Code\apps\eMart_Customer\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:133:13-37 Error:
Attribute receiver#com.razorpay.RzpTokenReceiver@exported value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:133:13-37
is also present at [com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.34] AndroidManifest.xml:44:13-36 value=(true).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:exported"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\Emart_V2.1_Source_Code\apps\eMart_Customer\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:130:13-36 Error:
Attribute activity#com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity@exported value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:130:13-36
is also present at [com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.34] AndroidManifest.xml:54:13-37 value=(false).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:exported"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/tools-replace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest
It appears that we are encountering the same problem once more.